# Not able to understand KL decomposition

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics

The bias-variance decomposition usually applies to regression data. We would like to obtain similar decomposition for classification,  when the prediction is given as a probability distribution over $C$ classes.
Let $P = [P_1, . . . , P_C ]$ be the ground truth class distribution associated to a particular input pattern. Assume the random estimator of class probabilities $$\bar{{P}} = [\bar{{P}}_1, . . . , \bar{{P}}_C ] $$ for the same input pattern. The error function is given by
the KL-divergence between the ground truth and the estimated probability distribution:
$$\text{Error} = E[D_{KL}(P||\bar{{P}})$$

First, we would like to determine the mean of the class distribution estimator $\bar{{P}}$. We define the mean as the distribution
that minimizes its expected KL divergence from the class distribution estimator, that is, the distribution
$R$ that optimizes
$$\begin{matrix}\min\\R \end{matrix} \space E[ D_{KL}(R||\bar{{P}})]$$

Show that the solution to the optimization problem above is given by
$$ R = [R_1, . . . , R_C ] $$
$$ \text{where} \space\space R_i = \frac{{\exp\space E[\log \bar{P_i} ]}}{{\sum_j\exp\space E[\log \bar{P_j}]}}  \space \space \space ∀ \space 1 ≤ i ≤ C.$$

P.S.: I have read about KL Decomposition But not able to understand this problem completely. If possible please give me any link I can go through to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't understand the minimum being taken over $RE$. I suspect that $E$ is a misplaced operator there.

Comment: Yes it was misplaced. sorry for the typo